# Redis from docker image redis:6.2.5-alpine3.14 can't start "Invalid LZF compressed string"

Tags: docker, redis

After restart docker container with redis:6.2.5-alpine3.14 it can't start with error:

```
[offset 55130] Internal error in RDB reading offset 0, function at rdb.c:411 -> Invalid LZF compressed string
```

Everything is OK after Redis storage was cleaned up:

```
# ls -la /redis/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x.  2 polkitd 1000    43 Oct  4 19:22 .
drw-r-----. 14 root    root   179 Sep  8 19:51 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 polkitd 1000 63907 Oct  4 19:13 dump.rdb
-rw-r--r--.  1 polkitd root  4096 Oct  4 19:22 .dump.rdb.swp
```

Could somebody explain what can be a reason of this issue?

Comment: Why do you have the `dump.rdb.swp` file? Is `dump.rdb` edited by `vi` or `vim`? You can check that with `sudo fuser dump.rdb`

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici Yes, I've spotted this file and it's also very suspicious for me. No, I've not tried to open this file.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the RDB database is corrupted. You should stop the container and restore the file from a backup. If you can't restore it, you can rename/move it to have a corrupted backup in case you want to restore it partially, then start the redis container.

If this is happening often, check if [AOF](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) (Append Only File) is better for you. You can have both RDB and AOF at the same time. For more details read also [Redis persistence demystified](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html).

To check the consistency of the RDB files you can use:

```
redis-check-dump dump.rdb
```

See [4.3.1 Verifying snapshots and append-only files](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-4-keeping-data-safe-and-ensuring-performance/4-3-handling-system-failures/4-3-1-verifying-snapshots-and-append-only-files/) for more details.

If you use a cluster, you can [recover one of the nodes](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/administering/troubleshooting/database-recovery/) with:

```
rladmin recover list  # To see the list of all files to be recovered

rladmin recover all
rladmin recover db <database_id|name>    # To recover only one DB
recover db only_configuration <db_name>  # To recover only the DB config

rladmin status     # To check which DBs were recovered
```

Also in a cluster it's possible to [recover the the DB](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/administering/troubleshooting/cluster-recovery/) with:

```
rladmin cluster recover ....
```

See: [cluster recover](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/rladmin/#cluster-recover) documentation